# How to select data between two dates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to select data between two dates. The date's format is in the code I copied. I have seen a lot of codes for this, but couldn't find anything with this format.

```
Dataset = Data_have[
    (Data_have['OrderDate'] >= "1SEP2007:00:00:00") & 
    (Data_have['OrderDate'] <= "31MAR2008:00:00:00")
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Pintang, how did you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using pandas, and that `data_have` is a DataFrame, the problem here is that pandas does not automatically recognized strings like `'1SEP2007:00:00:00'` as date-strings:

But it can if you [give it a little help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
import pandas as pd

data_have = pd.DataFrame(
    {'OrderDate': pd.date_range('2007-1-1', '2009-1-1', freq='M')})

start, end = pd.to_datetime(["1SEP2007:00:00:00", "31MAR2008:00:00:00"], 
                            format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
dataset = data_have[
    (data_have['OrderDate'] >= start) & 
    (data_have['OrderDate'] <= end)
]
print(dataset)
```

prints

```
    OrderDate
8  2007-09-30
9  2007-10-31
10 2007-11-30
11 2007-12-31
12 2008-01-31
13 2008-02-29
14 2008-03-31
```

---

Above, I'm also assuming that `OrderDate` contains values of dtype `datetime64[ns]` (parsed dates, as opposed to date strings). If `OrderDate` contains date-strings, then you'll need to parse them too:

```
data_have['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_have['OrderDate'], 
                                        format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

---

Pandas uses `dateutil` to parse date-strings. You can test if a date-string is 
automatically parsable by pandas by passing it to `pd.Timestamp`:

```
In [45]: pd.Timestamp("1SEP2007:00:00:00")
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

whereas, for example, `"1 SEP2007 00:00:00"` is automatically parsable:

```
In [49]: pd.Timestamp("1 SEP2007 00:00:00")
Out[49]: Timestamp('2007-09-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Might be useful to also include: `data_have['OrderDate'] = data_have.apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x['OrderDate'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'), axis=1)`

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added something similar, but using `pd.to_datetime` instead of `apply`.

Comment: Good deal. I'm new to Pandas so I didn't know about that shortcut.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive information and the link on Datetime dtypes. I was really struggling to format the column "orderdate".  I used the code below as you suggested then all problem solved:    data_have['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_have['OrderDate'],  format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')                                    I had 18484 rows that I needed for predictive modelling. Your quick reply  really helped. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, how did you select the codes in the highlighted lines?

Comment: Do you mean `%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S`? The meaning of this format code is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Although that page discusses format codes for use with `strftime` and `strptime`, the same format codes can be used in [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: I meant on the page in your reply there are some highlighted part(I don't know the right word) such as "data_have", "'1SEP2007:00:00:00'", and codes etc also hyperlink to the website. This question is not related to python!

Comment: Ah! Stackoverflow uses [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Surrounding text with backticks causes the text to be highlighted.